# Python: Why is my code ending with all CAPS?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie when it comes to python, so I am taking an online course. My problem is that when I tried to create a code to capitalize every other letter, it capitalizes all of my code. If you know what is wrong, please let me know.

```
def myfunc(*args):

    new_string = ''
    x = 0

    while x < len(args):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            new_string += args[x].upper() 
        else:
            new_string += args[x].lower()
        break
    return new_string
```

My input is:

```
myfunc('hello world')
```

and the Output is:

> 'HELLO WORLD'

Comment: You never change the value of `x`.

Comment: as @Aran-Fey pointed out, `1 % 2` will always `== 0`

Comment: Also, if you want to capitalise every other letter in a `string`, then I think you should replace `*args` in the function definition with a a single parameter: something like `string` or `word`

Comment: Why have three close-voters voted this question as off-topic? It looks like *a specific programming problem* which is on-topic as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Why is this being voted as off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

The following is what I would do. (Usage note: If a word ends in a capital, then the next word will start with a capital if separated by a *single* space.)

```
def myfunc(word):
    new_string = ''

    for i, char in enumerate(word):
        if char == ' ':
            continue
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_string += char.upper()
        else:
            new_string += char.lower()
    return new_string
```

Notes:

I replaced the `*args` parameter and made it `word` to give a clearer idea of what needs to be passed in to the function, and to make sure only 1 string is passed. I've omitted string type validation/checking.

when counting a position in a loop, use `enumerate()` to return a tuple as (index, item). This acts as a counter like your variable `x`, which I chose to name `i`

Generally use the parameter `'i'` to keep count instead of `x`, although this is merely style.

Iterate over a string to get its individual characters. Although a while loop with a counter is viable, for loops are cleaner and automatically return the correct item without having to manually index it from the string with your counter.

I added the first `if` statement to ignore whitespace characters, but I don't think it's necessary for this function.